# Running OpenGL project through Visual Studio produces intended output but running the .exe file directly produces incorrect output

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022, GLEW (static link) and GLFW (static link).

I am relatively new to OpenGL so I've been able to render simple stuff like triangles and squares while working with shaders. Everything actually works out with no errors when building with Visual Studio in either Release or Debug mode. But I happened to find the .exe file of my program and upon clicking it, I get a somewhat wrong output:

[image]

Intended output (building from Visual Studio)

[image]

Faulty output (running .exe file directly)

I dont know why but the program still correctly reads all my vertex positions but doesn't proceed with the fragment shading part. It may help to know that I'm getting following linker warnings:

1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

1>glew32s.lib(glew.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'glew32s.lib(glew.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info

In visual studio, I have set my 'Working Directory' as $(ProjectDir) which scopes to the directory containing the .vcxproj file and my Main.cpp file (entry point). This folder also contains a 'Resources' subfolder that contains my single shader file. I have a function which retrieves the shader file (I am storing both the vertex and fragment shader into 1 file) and simply returns the contents of the shader into a struct that holds the vertex shader and fragment shader source code separately.

```
ShaderSource allShaders = GetShaders("Resources/VertFrag.shader"); //Main.cpp

ShaderSource GetShaders(const std::string& filePath) { //ShaderLoading.cpp
enum class shaderType {
    NONE = -1, VERT = 0, FRAG = 1
};

std::string lineInFile;
std::ifstream shaderFile(filePath);
std::stringstream shaderSourcesArray[2];
shaderType currentShaderType = shaderType::VERT;

while (std::getline(shaderFile, lineInFile)) {
    if (lineInFile.find("#shader Vert") != std::string::npos) {
        currentShaderType = shaderType::VERT;
    }
    else if (lineInFile.find("#shader Frag") != std::string::npos) {
        currentShaderType = shaderType::FRAG;
    }
    else {
        shaderSourcesArray[static_cast<int>(currentShaderType)] << lineInFile << '\n';
    }
}

shaderFile.close();
return { shaderSourcesArray[0].str(), shaderSourcesArray[1].str() };
}
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  For all we know you're loading shaders from disk with relative paths.  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as base.

Comment: Hopefully lesson learned - always check for errors!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm actually in the same boat here, this is what I found:

When I has visual studio compile a release version and ran the code through the terminal I received the following output:

```
$ ./green-sim.exe
4.5.0 - Build 24.20.100.6346
Error whilst reading file: ERRNO #2
```

And that's when it hit me: We are compiling the shaders at runtime -> and the source path is wrong.

Here is my original shader compilation code:

```
// get source code
char* vertexShaderSource = ParseShader("res/shaders/vertex-shader.vert");
char* fragmentShaderSource = ParseShader("res/shaders/fragment-shader.frag");
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
// get source code
char* vertexShaderSource = ParseShader("C:/Users/my-user/projects/solution-folder/project-folder/res/shaders/vertex-shader.vert");
char* fragmentShaderSource = ParseShader("C:/Users/my-user/projects/solution-folder/project-folder/res/shaders/fragment-shader.frag");
```

Obviously you should try to use some kind of file-path macro or something to get your full shader path but that's the idea!

My code throws an error when I can't import the shaders, yours most likely lets it slides and your native shaders take over instead.